# How can I remove the ability for the user to go to the sides when my responsive menu is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work on a responsive menu using some JavaScript for functions, but I've a problem. So far, my menu is very functional, but I'd like that when it is open, the user doesn't have the opportunity to go on the sides. Here's the problem in video: http://screencast.com/t/yQkGV9XTJm

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
(function($)
{
    $('#side-block-toggle-icon').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('side-block');
        $('#expose-mask').toggle();
    });
    $('#expose-mask').click(function(e)
    {
        $('body').removeClass('side-block');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

my HTML code:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span id="side-block-toggle-icon" title="Navigation"></span>
        <div id="side-block">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="../." class="home active">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="../shop/shop.php" class="shop ">Shop</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="../community/" class="forums">Community</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="support ">Support</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 id="logo">
            <a href="../.">Logo</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>        
<!-- CONTAINER -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="breadcrumb-top" class="breadcrumb">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="./.." class="home">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 id="welcome-to" class="big-title">Web site for highly customized styles for the <a href="http://xenforo.com" target="_blank" style="border-bottom: 2px solid;">XenForo forum software</a>.</h1>
        <h1 id="all-available-styles" class="big-title">All available styles</h1>
        <p>Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.</p>
        <div id="breadcrumb-bottom" class="breadcrumb">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="./.." class="home">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="help" class="overlay-trigger" href="help.php">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span id="footer-copyright">
            <a href="./..">Coded by Dylan.</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay-box">
    <div class="overlay-box-container">
        <span class="overlay-box-closer" title="Close the overlay"></span>
        <h1 class="big-title">Help</h1>
        <p>Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="expose-mask" style="display: none;"></div>
    <script src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
```

and my CSS code:

```
.overlay-box
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 35%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    transition: opacity 500 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500 ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-box-container
{
    margin: 20px;
}

.overlay-box-closer:before
{
    content: "\f00d";
    position: absolute;
    top: -21px;
    right: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.big-title
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* BASE */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    font-weight: normal;
}

h1
{
    font-size: 25px;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 20px;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 18px;
}

h4
{
    font-size: 17px;
}

h5
{
    font-size: 15px;
}

h6
{
    font-size: 13px;
}

ul, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
    margin: 0;
}

ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

/* CORE */

html
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body
{
    background-color: #E6E9ED;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Amaranth, ABeeZee, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.wrapper
{
    max-width: 975px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

a
{
    color: #4D7799;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #CD3816;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:before,
#navigation a:after,
#side-block-toggle-icon:before,
#side-block-toggle-icon:after,
#all-available-styles:before,
#all-available-styles:after,
#slideshow-pause-icon:before,
#slideshow-pause-icon:after,
#slideshow-play-icon:before,
#slideshow-play-icon:after,
#join-us-now:before,
#join-us-now:after,
#footer a:before,
#footer a:after,
.overlay-box-closer:before,
.overlay-box-closer:after
{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

#navigation
{
    background-color: #283a4a;
    height: 60px;
}

#navigation li
{
    float: left;
}

#navigation a
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#navigation a:hover
{
    background-color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a.active
{
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Navigation icons */

#navigation a:before
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#navigation a.home:before
{
    content: "\f015";
}

#navigation a.shop:before
{
    content: "\f07a";
}

#navigation a.forums:before
{
    content: "\f086";
}

#navigation a.support:before
{
    content: "\f1cd";
}

#side-block-toggle-icon
{
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#side-block-toggle-icon:before
{
    content: "\f0c9";
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* HEADER */

#header
{
    background-color: #3d5e78;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: -75px;
}

#logo
{
    float: left;
}

#logo a
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
    line-height: 75px;
}

#logo a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* CONTAINER */

#container
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Breadcrumb */

.breadcrumb
{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 50px;
    margin: -20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.breadcrumb li
{
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb a
{
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0 1px 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover
{
    color: #CD3816;
}

.breadcrumb-separator
{
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#breadcrumb-top
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
}

#breadcrumb-bottom
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-top: #CCCCCC 1px solid;
}

#welcome-to,
#all-available-styles
{
    text-align: center;
}

#all-available-styles
{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#all-available-styles:before,
#all-available-styles:after
{
    content: "\f122";
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

#all-available-styles:before
{
    transform: rotate(250deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(250deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(250deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(250deg);
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#all-available-styles:after
{
    margin-left: 5px;
    transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: rotate(100deg) scaleX(-1);
}

/* FOOTER */

#footer
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#footer ul
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#footer li
{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#footer li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
{
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

#footer a
{
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0 1px 0;
}

#footer a:hover
{
    color: #CD3816;
}

#footer-copyright
{
    display: block;
    color: #808080;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0 1px 0;
}

#footer-copyright a
{
    color: #808080;
    text-shadow: #FFFFFF 0 1px 0;
}

#footer-copyright a:hover
{
    color: inherit;
}

/* Footer icons */

#footer a:before
{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#footer a.home:before
{
    content: "\f015";
}

#footer a.shop:before
{
    content: "\f07a";
}

#footer a.forums:before
{
    content: "\f086";
}

#footer a#help:before
{
    content: "\f1cd";
}

#expose-mask
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

/* RESPONSIVENESS */

@media screen and (max-width: 780px)
{
    .wrapper
    {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

    #navigation
    {
        position: inherit;
    }

    #navigation li, #navigation a:before
    {
        float: none;
        line-height: 0;
    }

    #side-block-toggle-icon
    {
        display: inherit;
    }

    #side-block
    {
        background-color: #283A4A;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 250px;
        transform: translateX(-250px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-250px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-250px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(-250px);
    }

    #side-block a
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .side-block
    {
        transform: translateX(250px);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(250px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(250px);
        -moz-transform: translateX(250px);
    }

    #side-block-toggle-icon a
    {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #logo
    {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #all-available-styles
    {
        font-size: 24.2px;
    }

    .slideshow-pause-and-play-icon
    {
        opacity: inherit;
    }
}
```

You can have a live preview here: http://nextgenfocus.com/test1/

I'd like have like this: http://foundation.zurb.com/

I know that putting a `overflow: hidden` to my `html`, the problem is fixed, but I lose the scroll bar... Do you have a solution?

Comment: Which browser is that, I don't have that problem in chrome.

Comment: No, the problem isn't related to browsers. You must remain pressed with your mouse to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your menu is in the wrapper. move your sidemenu out of the wrapper: [See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/0buLjL5q/)

```
<div id="side-block">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="../." class="home active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="../shop/shop.php" class="shop ">Shop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="../community/" class="forums">Community</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="support ">Support</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <span id="side-block-toggle-icon" title="Navigation"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's still not working on Chrome: http://screencast.com/t/jEeFErH6rP I'd like that it is impossible to go on the sides (as here): http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: I'm using Chrome too, and I am not able to scroll horizontally after the menu is opened.

Comment: Yes, me too, but you must left click and remain pressed to see the problem. You must remain pressed and then go on the right side and you will see the problem. Look the video: http://screencast.com/t/jEeFErH6rP